# Kubectl don't allow view resources in cluster from node in GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubectl

I have a trouble that i can't solve. So, I have k8s cluster on GCP. I can use kubectl from shell That opened directly to cluster. But when I use kubectl from node "I have The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?".
Also I use ./kube/config and it works about 5 minutes, and then again fail. 
Maybe someone use GCP and help me. Thank you.

Comment: Can you upload your kubeconfig format  ?

Comment: By the way what do you mean by `I use kubectl from node`

Comment: Please give more details about your issue, what you mean ""I have The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?"" ?

Comment: irvifa- I use Kubernetes cluster that provides GCP. When I connect directly from cloud shell. But when I connect from instance kubectl shows for client but for server it has mistake The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?"

Comment: Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14+", GitVersion:"v1.14.10-gke.27", GitCommit:"145f9e21a4515947d6fb10819e5a336aff1b6959", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-02-21T18:03:38Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.12b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Comment: I don't understand why you are trying to access "localhost:8080" could you clarify?

Comment: Yes of course,
I logged to the node using SSH
introduced the kubectl version command, it shows for the client but not for the server(actually this error), I don't know why node tries connect like localhost.
when I use /.kube/config (actually, I copy from shell cloud and paste to node ), and it works about 20 minutes

Comment: Ok, but why are you trying to run kubectl inside the node instead use cloud shell or your machine? You mentioned if you copy the `~/.kube/config.yaml` from the cloud shell it works for 20 minutes and after that it stopped?

Answer (score 0):

irvifa- I use Kubernetes cluster that provides GCP. When I connect directly from cloud shell. But when I connect from instance kubectl shows for client but for server it has mistake The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?"

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't use COS(Container-Optimized OS), your need to

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials "CLUSTER NAME"
```

By default COS will get credentials when you access to the node.

Comment: Unable to connect to the server: error executing access token command "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud config config-helper --format=json": err=fork/exec /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud: no such file or directory output= stderr=
after I use .kube/config on node

Comment: Which OS are you using in VM?